# JavaScript: Best way for update all tree items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tree

I try to create sidebar component in React and I have a data structure like bellow

```
const links = [
  {
    label: 'Item-1',
    url: '/item-1',
  },
  {
    label: 'Item-2',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Item-2-1',
        url: '/item-2-1',
      },
      {
        label: 'Item-2-2',
        url: '/item-2-2',
      },
      {
        label: 'Item-2-3',
        url: '/item-2-3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Item-3',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Item-3-1',
        url: '/item-3-1',
      },
      {
        label: 'Item-3-2',
        url: '/item-3-2',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

So the problem is let's say the user changed URL and URL something like that **http://localhost:90/item-2-3**.

And I need to activate this sidebar item from the sidebar and it can be nested. So firstly I need to deactivate all other sidebar items (I don't want multiple selected items in the sidebar) and after that activate the selected sidebar item.

Because that (if I'm correct) I need update all tree items let's say I add `active:false` field to all JSON and after that I need to find the correct tree item from tree (URL === item-2-3) add `active:true` and also update all parent json to `active:true` (for there are look selected/opened)

So my question is am I correct if I correct how can write this code optimal way? :/

Actually, I want to create a function and when calling this function like that `selectItemFromTree(links, '/item-2-2')` I get results like in bellow.

```
   const links = [
  {
    label: 'Item-1',
    url: '/item-1',
    active: false
  },
  {
    label: 'Item-2',
    active: true,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Item-2-1',
        url: '/item-2-1',
        active: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Item-2-2',
        url: '/item-2-2',
        active: true,
      },
      {
        label: 'Item-2-3',
        url: '/item-2-3',
        active: false
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Item-3',
    active: false,
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Item-3-1',
        url: '/item-3-1',
        active: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Item-3-2',
        url: '/item-3-2',
        active: false
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: You are describing several tasks. Please show your attempt, where it goes wrong, and focus on one issue only.

Comment: Don't worry about optimizing until you have something started to optimize. Your work flow sounds about right and it's not really that difficult to do either

Comment: @trincot I updated my question a little bit and added actually what I want to see :)

Comment: @charlietfl I added the result data structure which is I want to achieve.

Comment: OK but this isn't  a free code writing service or a "how to" tutorial service . What is expected is you show your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to traverse the tree recursively and update all the active statuses.

```js
const links=[{label:"Item-1",url:"/item-1"},{label:"Item-2",children:[{label:"Item-2-1",url:"/item-2-1"},{label:"Item-2-2",url:"/item-2-2"},{label:"Item-2-3",url:"/item-2-3"}]},{label:"Item-3",children:[{label:"Item-3-1",url:"/item-3-1"},{label:"Item-3-2",url:"/item-3-2"}]}];


const updateActiveLink = (links, url, parent = null) => {
   for (link of links) {
      link.active = false;
      if (link?.children) {
          updateActiveLink(link.children, url, link)
      }
      if (link.url === url) {
          link.active = true;
          if (!!parent) parent.active = true;
      }
   }
}

updateActiveLink(links, '/item-2-3');
          
console.log(links);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100%!important; top: 0}
```

**Note** that this method will mutate the links array.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) But in your example, it does not work how I need it exactly. So U just update the specific item from the tree but I need also to update this item's all parents to active: true. So actual problem this :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. You just need to pass a parent as a third parameter of the function and if any match found update the active status of the parents.